# jQuery question about init

Tags: jquery

I have been looking at some websites recently to see how they structure their jQuery and looking at Forrst.com they seem to have a pretty unique way of using it.

Here is a few snippets of code from their site.

```
Forrst = {
    showingTopClicker: false,
    currentUserID: -1,
    formKey: "",
    init: function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Forrst.formKey = $("meta[name=forrst-form-key]").attr("content");
            Forrst.currentUserID = $("meta[name=forrst-userid]").attr("content");
            Forrst.applyLibs();
            Stream.init();
            $("#promo-excerpt").jTruncate({
                length: 95
            });
            $(".notice-bar a.close").click(function () {
                return Forrst.hideNoticeBar()
            });
            PostForm.init();
            People.init();
            Comments.init();

Stream = {
    isLoading: false,
    streamPath: "",
    pageBy: "after",
    afterID: false,
    page: 1,
    extraParams: {},
    init: function () {
        if ($("#stream").length == 0) {
            return
        }
        Stream.redirectFromHash();
        $(".post-toggle > a").live("click", function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().children(".post").toggle("fast");
            $(this).parent().hide();
            return false
        });
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop() <= 300) {
                Stream.loadMore()
            }
        })
    },
    redirectFromHash: function () {
        if (window.location.hash != null && window.location.hash != "" && window.location.hash.match(/^#?after:/i)) {
            var b = window.location.pathname.split("/");
            var c = "";

Forrst.init();
```

Could anyone explain what is happening here and what the advantages are of building your code in this way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Guess: Forrst is used in a master page or some template, Stream is used in the derived view and has the specific page javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage is that your since your functions are sandboxed (namespaced is a better word), you can use canonical function names like `init` (and thus called like so: `Forrst.init()`) rather than `Forrst_init`. This allows function names to more clearly indicate what they're going to do.

Additionally, you don't clutter the global namespace. An example of why this is bad: if you name a global function `init`, and then later on you tried to add a jQuery plugin with a global function called `init`, you'd have problems and would have to rewrite some of that code to get rid of the function collisions. With namespaces you could call `MyPlugin.init()` and `OtherPlugin.init()`, avoiding this problem.